# How to set env vars from init container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, hashicorp-vault

Hello i have an init container in openshift that gets secrets from vault and i would like to save those secrets as env vars in the main container running on the pod i know that i can write them to a file then source them as env vars on the dockerfile but i need to do it in a way that doesnt include me making changes to the dockerfile of the main container and i wonderd wether its maybe posible To write to a specific file that gets auto sourced?
Problem i ran with that approach is that mounting to a dir overrides it so i cant mount to anywhere meaningful in the container

Help appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

You could mount an `emptyDir` into the pod :

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir

Then in the init container, output the env file into this mount location.

In the main container, override the entry point using the `command` directive, to source the env file from the same mount, and then run the main entrypoint command. So something like:

```yaml
command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "./decrypt-vars.sh && ./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

This would not need any changes to the Dockerfile (but you would need to change your yaml if the entrypoint script changes path/name within the image)

Comment: Is entrypoint.sh a script that is created whenever an image is built or is it something i need to write because i cant find it

Comment: `entrypoint.sh` is just an example. Each docker image has a command they run, normally described by the CMD directive (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). What the answer is doing, is doing something ELSE before running the entrypoint command (in this example, the entrypoint was `entrypoint.sh`. In another image, it could be something else, like running `nginx`)

Comment: If i understood you correctly for this to work i need to know the command the container needs to run correct?                      My aim is to make something as generic as possible so i wouldnt need to know the command the container needs to run

Comment: Correct. If you don't know, or can't access the details of the command the container runs on startup, or if you wanted to use the same method across multiple, unrelated containers, then this would not work. Maybe Hashicorp Vault might be of use (but I have not used it extensively enough to give any examples.) This might be useful reading: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pods-via-a-sidecar

Comment: Ok thank you anyway btw i am trying to improve upon the service you linked by vault,it serves the secrets as a file and i would like to save them as env vars